# How to align text in center using jspdf

Tags: jspdf

How to align text center using [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf).

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(40, 250, 'Hi How are you');
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are using the latest version (1.1.135) the api has changed some for the text function. It now reads as:

```
API.text = function(text, x, y, flags, angle, align);
```

If you don't need to use the flags or angle though, you can simply use:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text('Hi How are you', 40, 250, 'center');
```

Keep in mind that the center call uses the x parameter now as the center of the text string, and not the left most border as it does when rendering left aligned.

[Link to source](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/653f94aa5188b5eed26c355da21c78b7c048c877/jspdf.js#L1124)

Edit:

Alternately you can calculate the proper x offset to just use the text function normally like so:

```
var text = "Hi How are you",
    xOffset = (doc.internal.pageSize.width / 2) - (doc.getStringUnitWidth(text) * doc.internal.getFontSize() / 2); 
doc.text(text, xOffset, 250);
```

Comment: In version 1.3.4 the first method using `'center'` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @Blindsyde I'm not able to check this version's functionality atm, but looking at the code the signature is still the same. There is a change back in september that was meant to address alignment, so maybe it's the viewer youre using thats causing issues. Have you tried other pdf programs for this?

Comment: @GrouchyPanda I tried a few things before giving up and going with  a different approach detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327510/align-text-right-using-jspdf

Comment: Works on Jspdf@1.4.1.

Comment: Replace 'center' with  { align: 'center' }

Answer (score 19):

Angular 6.
Footer align to horizontally center

```ts
var doc = new jsPDF();
var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height || doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
var pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width || doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();


// FOOTER
let str = "Your footer text";
doc.setTextColor(100);
doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.text(str, pageWidth / 2, pageHeight  - 10, {align: 'center'});
doc.save("example.pdf");
```

Answer (score 4):

Above answers didn't work for me, I ended up doing the following to center the text

```
let textX = (doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - doc.getTextWidth(text))/2
doc.text(text, textX, textY);
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked:

```
var xOffset = doc.internal.pageSize.width / 2
        doc.text('hello world', xOffset, 8, {align: 'center'});
```

Answer (score 1):

2022: this works assuming your page width is 210 (default A4).

```
doc.text("This is centred text.", 105, 80, null, null, "center");
```

Here's a link to their live demo per the README:

http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This works somewhat, but isn't precise, if you know please tell me why.

I calculate the width of my text in order to center it myself.

For this, I used the getTextDimensions() method on my jsPDF object

```
var pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation : 'p',
            unit: 'px',
            format: [500, 750],
            putOnlyUsedFonts:true
        });

var textDimensions = pdf.getTextDimensions('MyText');
```

You can now use `textDimensions.w` to get text-width and `textDimensions.h` for height

Then use this to center your text.

```
var textWidth = textDimensions.w;

pdf.text('MyText', (pdfWidth / 2) - (textWidth / 2), 100);
```

**BUT:** You need to know your PDF's width to do this.

I 'solved' this by defining height and width myself, but you can easily find height and width of common formats online.

Like A4: 210mm*297mm.

Just remember to set `unit: 'mm'` when creating your jsPDF.

Comment: This is actually the correct way yo do it. But if you are using A4 210mm*297mm, you should note that var textDimensions = pdf.getTextDimensions('MyText'); returns px not mm so convert it by multiplying with 0.2645833333. This is why it is not being precise as you mentioned you missed this conversion. Otherwise great answer

Comment: I couldn't find info in doc which units are used for textDimensions neither for getTextWidth. Following @vinshaba idea getTextWidth * 1.21 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
// set midPage for variable use
var midPage = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()/2

// Default is 210 mm so default midway by value is 105
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text("Octonyan loves jsPDF", 105, 15, null, null, "center");


// Better to use a variable "midPage" (from above)
doc.setFontSize(30);
doc.text("Centered (USA), Centred (UK)", midPage , 30, null, null, "center");
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is correct. But I performed a slightly different task. I wanted my text to be align center or page to do that wrote the following code:

```
var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
let totalIncomePDF = "I am Usama";
doc.text(width/2, 195, totalIncomePDF, {align: 'center'});

let thresholdPDF = "I am from Pakistan";
doc.text(width/2, 245, thresholdPDF, {align: 'center'});
```

And the results I got are as follows:

[image: Image of results]

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

```
 pdf.text(`For Species: ${specieName}`, 300, finalY + 50, **{ align: 'center' }**);
```

Comment: Any idea how to give width to the text?

Comment: @NarenVerma y pdf.text('your text here', x, y, optionsObject}
where,
x is horizontal point where text should begin drawing, and
y is vertical point where it should draw on.

So, you can't give width, you can just give starting point X, and it will take width automatically.

Comment: ok. Actually, i have a text which is showing in one line horizontally. I have to break it

Comment: Is there a way we could make that `specieName` bold and rest of the remain normal?

Answer (score 0):

2022: I'm finding that JSPDF is buggy. It took a while to figure out how to install the advertised 'runs in a browser' implementation for a PHP app instead of a JS front end framework. There's a line that's required `window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;` that isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation, I had to go through a downloaded example piece by piece to find it. Now I'm finding that the center text function doesn't work. In 2 different local environments and a JSFiddle, on multiple browsers, it sends the text off the left side of the page when the align:center option is implemented. While the above solution works, it breaks down if text is longer than one line, which, incidentally, is another out of the box bug - the text runs out of the document instead of wrapping, and there is no wrap option. So, it seems after all these hours I'm out of luck and I'll have to go a different route. Plugin is not maintained and this should be noted in documentation. Recommend to not waste your time.