# Jspdf floating items to the right

Tags: jspdf

Am tryinng to align some items to the right and incase of lengthy texts extend it to the left

SO i have added

```
///others

doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.setFontSize(9);
doc.setTextColor("#52575A")
doc.text(doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()-70, 17, "Email: testhere@testingahugeandlengthyemail.com");
doc.text(doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()-70, 22, "Tel: 83473487348347834734843");
doc.textWithLink('Website: https://test.test.com',doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()-70 , 27, { url: 'https://ecommerce.soradius.co.ke' });
 doc.save('test.pdf')
```

The above code generates a pdf 
[image]

From the above code am aligning my texts to the left by setting it 70px from the page width.

When the text on the email increases its cropped away. How can i set the text to the right and make it expand to the left.

I have checked [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327510/align-text-right-using-jspdf) but still doesnt align correctly

Comment: doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() returns 210 as width whose units are different from that of px which you are trying to set for aligning at left

Comment: @NagaSaiA How can i then ensure that even though the email is large the text expands to the left to ensure its not cropped and its on the left side as per the image above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using jspdf units and doc.getTextWidth() to calculate email text width

1. Calculate difference of text width and 70 and using for spacing will avoid cropping of text
2. Adjusting spacing with text width will avoid spacing on other text sections

```js
var content = document.getElementById('txtContent'),
button = document.getElementById('btnDownload');

function generatePDF(){
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm','a4');

doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.setFontSize(9);
doc.setTextColor("#52575A")
  let width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()
  let emailText = "Email: testhere@testingahugeandlengthyemail.com"
  let txtWidth = doc.getTextWidth(emailText) > 70 ? doc.getTextWidth(emailText) - 70: 0;
  console.log("width", width, txtWidth)
doc.text(width - 70 - Math.ceil(txtWidth), 17, emailText);
doc.text(width-70, 22, "Tel: 83473487348347834734843");
doc.textWithLink('Website: https://test.test.com',width-70 , 27, { url: 'https://ecommerce.soradius.co.ke' });
 doc.save('test.pdf')
}

button.addEventListener('click', generatePDF);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<h1>jsPDF Demo</h1>

<textarea id="txtContent" cols="60" rows="15"></textarea>
<br />
<button id="btnDownload"> Download PDF </button>
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yrxZOY

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this answers helps for someone facing the same issue



    var str = 'Page 1 of 1'
    var pageSize = doc.internal.pageSize
    var pageHeight = pageSize.height ? pageSize.height : pageSize.getHeight()
    var pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width || doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    var txtwidth = doc.getTextWidth(str);               
    doc.text(str, pageWidth - (data.set`enter code here`tings.margin.left * 2) - txtwidth, pageHeight - 10)



[Got Expected Output][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKAxi.png
```